# Empty string before load

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var22 = $(".box .title").eq(0).text()
```

I use the previous command and it is always have something to give back. However there are some times in which I receive an empty string but when I go to check I can see there is content. I believe it has something to do with the page load. Possible I could wait until the page load?

How can I make it (with load())?

`$(".box .title").eq(0).text()` if I take back this `Uncaught ReferenceError: box is not defined(…)` how can I make it to give back something which is not undefined?

Comment: Yes, use `ready()`. Add this code in `ready` handler

Answer (score 3):

You need to put it inside **[document ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var var22 = $(".box .title").eq(0).text();
  console.log(var22);
});
```

> A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

Taken from **https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/**

Comment: @eabcde If you just used `var var22 = $(".box .title").eq(0).text();` ,  at that time the object you are referencing is not ready, so you will get as undefined

Comment: it is not undefined it is "" and when I go to the console in developer tools I can see it is not an empty string